# How to automatic call function every x time

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call function in every “X” minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053585/how-to-call-function-in-every-x-minute)

How to periodically call a certain function?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkAlert];   
}



-(void)checkAlert{
    // Server output Alert Note
    NSString *alert_note_hostStr = @"http://www.loxleyintranet.com/MobileApplication/xml/alert_note.php";
    NSData *alert_note_dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:alert_note_hostStr]];
    NSString *alert_note_serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:alert_note_dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if ([alert_note_serverOutput isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        alertImage.hidden = YES;
        alertLabel.hidden = YES;
        underMainBG.hidden = YES;
        alertLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Alert"];
    }else{    
        alertLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You've Got Note (%@)" ,alert_note_serverOutput];

    }    
}
```

How can I call `[self checkAlert];` every `x` minutes or seconds?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self
                      selector:@selector(checkAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`.

Comment: Not working for me...

Comment: make repeat = NO, rather to have a better output. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // the interval is in seconds...
```

...then your `myTimerTick:` method should look like this..

```
-(void)myTimerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(some_contiditon)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate]; //to stop and invalidate the timer.
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Still in 2016.